# What's an easy way to check for null values on properties with custom annotation?

Tags: java

I have a custom annotation on fields in a class that I want to ensure it's not null. What's the easiest way to do it? Hoping there's a library out there.

Comment: Get all fields in that class that are annotated with your annotation (I'm not sure whether the JDK's reflection classes already provide a simple way for that but there are reflection libraries that do), get the field values for some object and check.

Comment: for this you can use JSR-303 (bean validation)